# Rational distance from a regular polygon.

Tags: geometry, number-theory, triangles, polygons

Consider a regular n-gon with side length $A$.

Let $p$ be a point in the polygon.
Let the distances from $p$ to the corners of the n-gon be $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$

Are there solutions with $A,x_1,x_2,...x_n$ all positive integers and $gcd(A,x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = 1$.

For the triangle ( $n=3$) this question has been answered already here

[Do there exist an infinite number of 'rational' points in the equilateral triangle $ABC$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485755/do-there-exist-an-infinite-number-of-rational-points-in-the-equilateral-triang)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180191/rational-distance-from-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle

--

I assume for sufficiently large $n$ there are no solutions ?

In particular im intrested in $n=4,5,6$.

Comment: Another useful source of information:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180191/rational-distance-from-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle

Comment: Is $A$ rational? Should $ a,b,c $ be individually be rational ? Or should they all be positive integers? The Fermat point is fixed for the minimum sum.

Comment: Im considering a generalization to avoid the duplicate. But I have to read and think first.

Comment: I edited too generalize. Therefore voted to reopen. Plz vote reopen too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Viviani's theorem that says $ x + y + z $ is invariant.

Compute $x=y=z$ for $A=1$.

Comment: Vivani theorem says that theant sum of distances to the _sides_ is constant. $x,y,z$ are distances to the _corners_.

Comment: In Viviani's Theorem, the invariant is the sum of the distances to the sides, not the corners.  No?

Comment: Hmm. So it is the distance to the middle of the sides ? Can this still be useful ?

Comment: @mick Not the distance to the middle of the sides. It's a length of the shortest line segment connecting the point and the line segment.

Comment: Thanks Wojowu. I need to think.

Comment: I edited and voted for reopen.