# Number of integer points inside an equilateral triangle with side length $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, discrete-geometry

Does there exist any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exist at least one point **inside** of(not on the border) an equilateral triangle with side length $n$ ,which its distances to the vertices be **integers**?

If yes; can anyone give a formula for the number of such points for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

**Notice:** We already know by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485755/do-there-exist-an-infinite-number-of-rational-points-in-the-equilateral-triang) and for further results [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180191/rational-distance-from-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle) ,that there are infinite number of points with rational distances inside an equilateral triangle with side length one, but what about integers?

Comment: Well as soon as your $n$ is big enough to make the incircle have diameter $> \sqrt{2}$ you will have an integer point in your triangle...

Comment: Note that generally we can count the lattice points using Pick's area formula, e.g. as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27637/242).

Comment: @PrudiiArca so where do you choose your point location?

Comment: @MasM it shouldn’t matter. Any circle of diameter $>\sqrt{2}$ contains an integer point in its inside.

Comment: @BillDubuque interesting lattice points but what would be achieved here from that? the condition here seems different.

Comment: @PrudiiArca how do you prove its existence?

Comment: Multiply rationals by the common denominator, and you'll have integers. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sure this is what we have from that post, what is different here is that the formula for $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, infinitely many such triangles exist. Possible n are 112, 147, 185, 224, 273, 283, 294, 331...... See https://oeis.org/A061281

Comment: Great, would you explain more about how they achieved these numbers? What about a formula for the number of integer points inside a quadrilateral triangle for each $n$

Comment: I only can tell a you a recipe how I could reproduce these numbers. Define the coordinates P1, P2, P3  of the vertices of an equilateral triangle with edge length n  in a cartesian coordinate system and the coordinate C of all triangles with integer edge lengths a<=b<n which share the edge P1P2  with the equilateral triangle and with the 3rd vertex C inside the equilateral triangle. Check if CP3 is an integer for any of these possible inner points C.

Comment: I don't think this is the way computers may calculate the solutions ,I think there would be a subtle way to come up with numerical calculations of the tremendous diophantine equation behind it.

Comment: @MasM Which tremendous diophantine equation? And it is exactly the way how computers can compute the solutions for n in the order about 10^3 to 10^4. I am quite  sure that no explicit formula exists.